# How to store foreign key in table

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys

I want to store a foreign key in my `page_master` table and the foreign key is coming from the `business_master` table.

This is my controller method:

```
$page = new Page();
$page->page_name = Input::get('page_name');
$page->page_url  = Input::get('page_url');
$page->business()->business_id;
$page->save();

$resultArray = ['status' => 1, 'message' => 'Page url added!', dataArray' => $page];
```

My page_master model:

```
protected $table = 'page_master';
protected $fillable = ['business_id','page_url','page_name'];

public function business()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Business','business_id','id');
}
```

Here the foreign key is business_id, but when I make this request, it says:

> ErrorException: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::$business_id

How can I store the business_id as a foreign key? Any help will be highly appreciated!

```
                    $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('business_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('page_url')->unique();
        $table->string('page_name');
        $table->tinyInteger('is_live')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
```

Comment: no its fine here is not any problem

Comment: any other solution please

Comment: Please provide the migration of the `Page` model.

Comment: i add migration please see

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the error is in this line:

```
$page->business()->business_id;
```

You are trying to get a property from a relationship object.

You should try to use `attach` function after saving the model:

```
$businessId = Input::get('business_id');
$page->business()->attach($businessId);
```

About the foreign key issue, you need to use foreign in your migration files:

```
$table->foreign('business_id')->references('id')->on('business_master');
```

Take a look here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Answer (score 0):

This code should work for  you.

```
$page = new Page();
$page->page_name = Input::get('page_name');
$page->page_url  = Input::get('page_url');
$page->business_id = $businessId;
$page->save();
```

The error is generated by this line of code **$page->business()->business_id;** That actually is used to retrieve relationship data.

People also use attach **$page->business()->attach($businessId);** but I prefer simplicity. Hence, I always stick with this convention **$page->business_id = $businessId;**

To add foreign key in your migration:

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('business_id')->unsigned();
$table->string('page_url')->unique();
$table->string('page_name');
$table->tinyInteger('is_live')->nullable();
$table->foreign('business_id')->references('id')->on('business_master');
$table->timestamps();
```

If you use foreign_key you must think for cascade actions. To learn more about foreign constrains, look at the [document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#foreign-key-constraints).